# SQL get records in the same week

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a table that contains records with a column indicates the Date. Given a record, I would like to select all records that are in the same week as the record. How can SQL do that?

I should say that I'm using SQLite.

Comment: Seems like you'd have to use something like this http://www.objectreference.net/post/SQL-Find-last-week-date-range.aspx  But modified so that the start date is based off the date of the record you've selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DATEPART` with `wk` to get the current week. Then just check for equality.
In this case, I have also checked `yy` to make sure that you do not check the year of a previous week.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATEPART(wk, TABLE.DATECOLUMN) 
        = DATEPART(wk, (SELECT DATECOLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ID = GivenID))
    AND DATEPART(yy, TABLE.DATECOLUMN) = DATEPART(yy, (SELECT DATECOLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE   ID = GivenID))
```

**UPDATE FOR SQLITE**

To do this in SQLLite, [Refer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075039/sqlite3how-to-retrieve-the-date-part-out-of-a-datetime-result-column) and then [this article that states %W is what you use to get week and %Y for year](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html). Which gives you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE STRFTIME('%W', TABLE.DATECOLUMN) 
        = STRFTIME('%W', (SELECT DATECOLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ID = GivenID))
    AND STRFTIME('%Y', TABLE.DATECOLUMN) 
        = STRFTIME('%Y', (SELECT DATECOLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ID = GivenID))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `datediff()` function:

```
datediff(ww,start_date,end_date) < 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) to specify the records you want.

```
 SELECT * FROM records WHERE datecolumn between 'YYYY/MM/DD' AND 'YYYY/MM/DD'
```