# how to convert datetime.timedelta(0, 79200) to minutes and seconds

Tags: python, django

```
+-----------+----------+
| from_time | to_time  |
+-----------+----------+
| 09:00:00  | 22:00:00 |
+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

that is my actual SQL table which is in `Hours:minutes:seconds format`. when I query with `select from_time, to_time from Tollapp_configure;`, in django I got the out put as `((datetime.timedelta(0, 32400), datetime.timedelta(0, 79200)),)`.

How can I convert `((datetime.timedelta(0, 32400), datetime.timedelta(0, 79200)),)` into actual Hours minutes and seconds (22:00:00 format).

My django model looks like this:

```
class Configure (models.Model):
    from_time = models.TimeField()
    to_time = models.TimeField()
```

Comment: `print(datetime.timedelta(0, 32400))`  prints  `9:00:00`  what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How do I get time from a datetime.timedelta object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764184/python-how-do-i-get-time-from-a-datetime-timedelta-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

### Convert the timedelta into a date using python

```
>>> import datetime
>>> startTime = datetime.timedelta(0, 54915)
>>> startTime = (datetime.datetime.min + startTime).time()
>>> startTime
datetime.time(15, 15, 15)
```

### Get date in format through SQL

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', datetime) FROM your_table;
```

Source: [How to retrieve the Date part out of a Datetime result column in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7075039/9770208)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Patrick Artner thanks for your help. sorry, I din't saw by printing actually. I tried every thing except print

Comment: @JanardhanReddy.Meeniga if you've fixed the issue don't forget to close the question